# Log10_trans function in R removes axis titles

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code I used to produce graphs. I used scale_x_continuous instead of scale_x_log10 because I was having the same error described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987208/how-to-scale-x-axis-and-add-ticks-in-r). However, when I do that, my x-axis titles disappear and are replaced by log-10. How do I fix this?

````
```{r echo=FALSE, Univariate_Plots}
grid.arrange(ggplot(data = prw,
                    aes(x = fixed.acidity)) + 
               geom_histogram(binwidth = .2) +
               scale_x_continuous(log10_trans(), limits = c(0, 20)),

ggplot(data = prw,
       aes(x = volatile.acidity)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = .03) +
  scale_x_continuous(log10_trans(), limits = c(0, 1.5)),

ggplot(data = prw,
       aes(x = citric.acid)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = .05) +
  scale_x_continuous(log10_trans(), limits = c(0,1)),

ggplot(data = prw,
       aes(x = free.sulfur.dioxide)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = .075) +
  scale_x_log10(),

ggplot(data = prw,
       aes(x = total.sulfur.dioxide)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 3) +
  scale_x_continuous(log10_trans(), limits = c(0, 120)),

ggplot(data = prw,
       aes(x = sulphates)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = .05) +
  scale_x_continuous(log10_trans(), limits = c(0,2)),
ncol = 3)
```
````

P.S. Does using print screen not work? What are some suggestions for posting an image from R onto Stackoverflow? (apart from uploading online to an image provider"

Comment: Without a [minimal reproducible data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) it's difficult to know what's happening, but can you try transforming the data first then plotting that new column?

Comment: Can you just use ```+ xlab("my label")``` ?

Comment: The xlab function does not work. I will try and work on a reproducible dataset!